# operation failed in error: <AFHTTPRequestOperationManager: 0x80010ce0, baseURL: (null), operationQueue:

Tags: ios, api, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking Framework for calling API and sometimes I am not getting any response from server while API call:

Here is my code snippet:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:timeOutInterval];
[manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",MainUrl,apiName] parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSArray *arrData = responseObject;
    NSLog(@"%@",arrData);
    NSString *strCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrData valueForKey:@"success"]];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", manager);
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Please check your internet connection" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}];
```

I get below error :

```
Error: <AFHTTPRequestOperationManager: 0x80010ce0, baseURL: (null), operationQueue: <NSOperationQueue: 0x80010ca0>{name = 'NSOperationQueue 0x80010ca0'}>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

In ios 9.1
AFNetworking  2.5

Comment: Can you display error and not manager in failure block, this might tell you more about the failure reason.

Comment: I got this  in error :

Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=

Comment: Looks like network issue, either network connection was lost on device or server was down. Worth checking the device network status if error happens. Maybe using AFNetworkReachabilityManager to check if isReachable and log the status. Or just checking in browser if api responds.

Comment: But in android same App there is no issue

Comment: So server is fine, you can try to log more inforamtion if error occurs and setup the AFManager - responseSerializer and other settings. For example for json reponse you should use :  manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

Comment: Ya i am using AFJSONRequestSerializer already ...